# changePage and href not loading second page with phonegap + Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying all kind of things with no success.
I have a Phonegap application with JQuery mobile that I test on my Samsung android 2.3.3 device (the first generation).
I'm loading a splash screen reside in index.html while doing all kind of stuff on the background. Then I'm calling `$.mobile.changePage('scenario1.html');` which reside in another file. This file has many pages.
The first page is loaded but when I call the next page it does not load.
I used `$.mobile.changePage('#page2')` which didn't work so I replace it with a simple `<a href="#page2">Next</>` which still does not work.
Please help since I'm clueless.

Comment: Do you have jQuery and jQuery Mobile linked on every page? Also can you post some of your file structure?

Comment: Did you fix it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I did not. Due to time constraint I just put all the code in one index.html